# Do these results look right for 4xSATA in RAID 10? The writes are faster than the reads?

Tags: performance, raid, benchmark

Do these results look right for a RAID-10 consisting of 4x1TB Samsung F3 SATA drives connected via a Dell Precision T3500's integrated RAID controller (which I believe is an Intel-based "FakeRAID")?

I understand speeds will vary based on the controller, but I was surprised to see that the writes were consistently faster than the reads - which seemed counter-intuitive.

Screenshot of benchmark from ATTO Disk Benchmark 2.46:  http://imageshack.us/f/851/drivebenchmark3.jpg/

RAID Settings (from Intel Rapid Storage Technology applet):
Raid Level:  1+0 (RAID 10)
Stripe Size:  64KB
Write-back cache: Enabled

Physical Disk Settings (from Intel Rapid Storage Technology applet):
NCQ: Yes
Disk data cache: Enabled

Comment: Disable the write-back cache (write through) and run the test again.  I think you'll find that is what's contributing to the high write throughput.

Answer (score 1):

As the commenter mentioned, I think you are seeing the amazing effects of cache on your controller or disks themselves. This is one of the reasons I always make sure that my test is writing more data than the cache sizes and the RAM available on the system combined (e.g. run a MUCH larger test than just 256MB, and you'll see things level out over the long run).